# Git pull confusion

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Our team uses Git and GitHub for code repository and code review.

Our typical process when you develop a new feature is:

```
git checkout master
git pull <company> master
git checkout -b <feature_branch>

<develop>

git pull <company> master
git push --set-upstream origin <feature_branch>

<create Pull Request in GitHub into <company> master>
<Code Review in GitHub>
```

There is one member on our team, that seems to do something else sometimes (he thinks he followed this process).

We see something weird when someone makes changes while he develops his feature, then when he pulls in that changed code.  His PR doesn't list the commits that he pulled in (from other people) and the diff shows the pulled in code as code he changed, but the code is identical.

Could it be that he called `rebase` (I admit I don't understand what rebase does)?  Could it be that he called git fetch to get the code, but never called git merge (that doesn't seem like the issue)?  What could it be?

See image:
[image: Identical code]

Comment: Gotta admit, I did laugh out loud at `notifyOfJobInJeopardy`, considering it's a Git and workflow question.

Comment: More seriously, this *could* easily be a line ending thing; the line endings of that particular code were different before he touched and/or saved the file.  What machines do you all work on; is a mix between different OSes?

Comment: @Makato I was wondering about line endings.  We all use Windows :( but before switching to git, we always used LF line endings.  Now on Git we just use the default behavior.  I think I will set up the projects to use eol=LF, but for now we don't. Is there a way to check the line endings in GitHub?  Is it weird that his PR doesn't list the other commits that he pulled in? Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Windows uses CRLF by default for the line endings. Start there; figure out if it really is a line ending difference by checking via Git CLI (check if `git config --global core.autocrlf` returns anything on the other developer's machine).